# Zocialcss CSS button background changes to white.

Tags: html, css

I am trying to incorporate ZocialCSS buttons in my site but the color of the background changes automatically to white when I insert them instead of retaining the rest of the buttons default color.

```
<div className="form-group">
    <div className="col-sm-offset-2 zocial facebook">
        <button class="zocial facebook">
        Sign in with Facebook
        </button>
    </div>      
</div>
```

I works in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bc6Et/, but in my computer, the class part is ignored, so I just get a plain HTML button.

Here is a picture of what it looks like when I write the `zocial facebook` within the `className` part:

[image]

Everyone is saying I should use `class` instead of `className`, but it gets ignored wherever I substitute it. Does anyone know why?

*Additional comments*

- I am using React.
- I have a index.html file that calls a js file, containing a render function with the above HTML code in it.

**ANSWER**
Incluiding `className` within `button` worked perfectly:

```
<div className="form-group">
     <div className="col-sm-offset-2">
           <button className="zocial facebook">
                 Log in with Facebook
           </button>
     </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: className="zocial facebook" ? dont u mean class = "zocial facebook" ?

Comment: when I use _class_ instead of _className_, this is the button I get: http://jsfiddle.net/Bc6Et/

Comment: do you have your own css that does something with the button element? I've never used Zocial, but it appears to me that the css is applied just to the element that you give the zocial class to.

Answer (score 0):

You need your CSS to affect the `<button>` within your `<div>`.

Also, it should be `class` instead of `className`

```
<div class="zocial facebook">
  <button>Log in with Facebook</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.zocial.facebook button {
  background-color: #somecolor
}
```

Or simply put the same class to the button as well as the div:

```
<div class="zocial facebook">
  <button class="zocial facebook">Log in with Facebook</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Whenever I use `class` instead of `className`, my code totally ignores the styling and just ouputs plain HTML without formatting. Any idea why?

Comment: UPDATE: I did `<button className="zocial facebook">Log in..</button> `and it worked. So changing to class was not it. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

First you should use "class=" not "className="

If background color is still imported after correcting, you can do the following:

you can override css by adding element styles

```
<div class="zocial facebook" style="background: none">
```

or

```
<div class="zocial facebook" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
```

you can also rewrite the css for .zocial facebook by targeting it in a style tag

```
<style>
    .zocial facebook {background: none; background-color: rgba(0,0,0 0);}
</style>
```

Comment: when I use _class_ instead of _className_, this is the button I get (a HTML button with no formatting): jsfiddle.net/Bc6Et

Comment: It looks like you're using buttons instead of anchor tags? Have you copied all the css from zocial and updated to use buttons as well?

Comment: UPDATE: I did `<button className="zocial facebook">Log in..</button> `and it worked. So changing to class was not it. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER Incluiding `className` within `button` worked perfectly:

```
<div className="form-group">
    <div className="col-sm-offset-2">
       <button className="zocial facebook">
             Log in with Facebook
       </button>
    </div>      
</div>
```